# Why doesn't Selenium take the name of element

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a dropdown menu that I want to select. But the problem I get is that testing+selenium won't take the name, and gives an error that I can't find it.

This is the piece with the dropdown box

The HTMl page where I got stuck to, it's the select with "kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
<div id="titel">
<div id="id7" style="text-align: right">
</div>
<div id="bannerStart"> </div>
<div id="id9"> </div>
<div id="ida"> </div>
<div id="inhoud">
<div id="content">
<div id="idb">
<br>
<h1>Kies rol</h1>
<div id="idc" style="display:none"> </div>
<div id="idd" style="display:none"> </div>
<div id="ide" style="display:none"> </div>
<form id="idf" action="?wicket:interface=:1:contentPanel:form::IFormSubmitListener::" method="post">
<div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden">
<table class="filterbox" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="id13">
<td class="filterboxCol1">
<td class="filterboxCol2">
<select name="kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel">
</td>
<td class="filterboxCol1"> </td>
<td class="filterboxCol2"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="id11" class="defaultButton" type="submit" onclick="var wcall=wicketSubmitFormById('idf', '?wicket:interface=:1:contentPanel:form:kiesRolButton::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true', 'kiesRolButton' ,function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$$(this)&&Wicket.$$('idf')}.bind(this));;; return false;" value="Kies" name="kiesRolButton">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="id12"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this dropdown box added to the page dynamically? In other words, is there some other event that needs to happen before the dropdown box shows up?

Comment: Your code should work with the example provided. So something else must be going on. Is your app accessible anywhere where we could look?

Comment: I think the dropdown box is dynamically. Because there is a dropdown box above and there needs to be a value first in it before you can see this dropdown box. And the app is localhost and can't be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the name and I think the :
But I found the piece of code with xpath that I can use and where he find's the right select

```
select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='filterbox']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='filterboxCol2']/select")));
    select.selectByVisibleText(maatregel);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python the solution will look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("filterboxCol2").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("filterboxCol2")).select_by_visible_text("Maatwerk")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value=\"1\"]").click()
```

You can try to use the "class name" instead of the "name" and see if it will pass.
I do not have Selenium in Java but the equivalent should look similar to this (using also the "name" type):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel")))
    .selectByVisibleText("Maatwerk");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"1\"]")).click();
```

Comment: This also will keep giving my error that he can't locate the element

Comment: Can you try to replace the By.name with (I do not know how it is exactly in Java) By.className("filterboxCol2")....

Comment: I tried that before but then I got the error that the element should be "select" but was "td"

Comment: Can you try to use the xpath then, this way you will be sure that the correct elements will be selected. And later, when the code runs successfully, you can which to another type and remove the xpath. Personally, when I stuck with Selenium like this, I always switch to the xpath to move further. :)

Comment: Is this Xpath this what I need to use:/html/body/div[5]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select   or do I need to reform this and in what? The xpath copied here is the one I get from firebug

Comment: I am using Chrome to take the Xpath and I am very statisfied with it. This is a real example of Drop Down Xpath that I have:
"//select[@name='xxxxxxx.yyyy']/option[text()='Completed']".
Please note that you have to switch to the actual IFrame where the Drop Down is, if any.

Comment: Additionally, if you locate the Drop Down entry this way, using Xpath, then you only need one line to switch to the new value - just perform a click() on this Xpath.
Unfortunately I cannot extract your Xpath because I miss the code.

Comment: I have added the html code to my question the select I want is kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel

Answer (score 0):

you have to click twice

driver.findElement(By.name("kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("XXXXX")).click();

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem. By using `xPath`.

Example:

```
<div class = "example">

  <table class="tableclass">
     <tbody class="tbodyclass">
       <tr class="tr1">
         <td class="td11">
         <select class = "selectclass">
         <option>java</option>
         <option>c#</option>
         </select>
         </td>

         <td class="td12">
         <select class = "selectclass">
         <option>jworld</option>
         <option>c#world</option>
         </select>
         </td>
         </tr>

      <tr class="tr2">
         <td class="td21">
         <select class = "selectclass">
         <option>Andorid</option>
         <option>Windows</option>
         </select>
         </td>

         <td class="td22">
         <select class = "selectclass">
         <option>great</option>
         <option>Nice</option>
         </select>
         </td>
         </tr>

       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
```

If you want to select `Java` from the drop down, then you have to used

> public class TestingExample{
>
> private WebDriver driver; private WebElement element; private
>   List elements;
>
> @BeforeClass 
>     public void openBrowser(){
>
> driver= new FirefoxDriver();
>
> }
>
> @Test 
>     public void testMethod(){
>
> driver.get("pass your website link"); Thread.sleep(3000); // milli sec
>
> element=driver.
>              findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select"));
>
> Thread.sleep(3000);       Select select = new Select(element);        elements
>   = select.getOptions(); // number of Options in that select tag        for (WebElement myelement : elements) {   // iterate the same
>
> ```
>       System.out.println(myelement.getText());            Thread.sleep(2000);
>       if (myelement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("java")) {
>           Thread.sleep(2000);
>           myelement.click();
>           break;          }       }       Thread.sleep(5000); } }
> ```
>
> Key things are 
>    1.) "//div[@class='element'] should be the parent and can be changed to  //*[@class 'element'] which means any tag which has class name as element."

2.) why tr[1] = because i want to choose an option from select tag which belongs to 1st row.
    If you want to choose `Android` then

> @Test public void testMethod(){
>
> driver.get("pass your website link"); Thread.sleep(3000); // milli sec
>   element=driver.
>              findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select"));
>   Select select = new Select(element);      elements = select.getOptions();
>   // number of Options in that select tag       for (WebElement myelement :
>   elements) {   // iterate the same
>
> ```
>       System.out.println(myelement.getText());            Thread.sleep(2000);
>       if (myelement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Andorid")) {
>           Thread.sleep(2000);
>           myelement.click();
>           break;          }       }       Thread.sleep(5000); }
> ```
>
> Change tr[1] to tr[2] to choose `android`.

3.) why td[1] cause `java` or `andorid` are in td[1] for there respective tr. If you want to choose option as `jworld` then

> @Test public void testMethod(){
>
> driver.get("pass your website link"); Thread.sleep(3000); // milli sec
>   element=driver.
>              findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='example']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select"));
>
> Select select = new Select(element);      elements = select.getOptions();
>   // number of Options in that select tag       for (WebElement myelement :
>   elements) {   // iterate the same
>
> ```
>       System.out.println(myelement.getText());            Thread.sleep(2000);
>       if (myelement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("jworld")) {
>           Thread.sleep(2000);
>           myelement.click();
>           break;          }       }       Thread.sleep(5000); }
> ```

Try this it will work.

All ways try to find a parent for it and then proceed to the child
using `xpath` as given in the above example.

Comment: Is there any way you could clean up this mess?

Comment: @SiKing If you feel this as a mess then give the answer for the above Question than wasting time by commenting unwanted things...

Comment: This one also doesn't work I get te error unable to locate xpath,the xpath I get from firebug is this one:/html/body/div[5]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select

Comment: Could you please give the html page properly would help

Comment: I have added the HTMl to the question

Comment: Which one do you wan to choose as in example

Comment: I want to choose the select with the name:kiesMaatregelPanel:maatregel